# Replacing list item with contents of another list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python), but instead of replacing one item with another, I'd like to replace any occurrences of one item with the contents of a list.

```
orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c' ]
repl = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
desired = [ 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]

# these are all incorrect, or fail to compile
[ repl if x == 'c' else x for x in orig ]
[ [a for a in orig] if x == 'c' else x for x in orig ]
[ (a for a in orig) if x == 'c' else x for x in orig ]
[ a for a in orig if x == 'c' else x for x in orig ]
```

Edit: made it clear I meant to replace *all* occurrences of the item, rather than just the first. (Apologies to anyone who didn't cover that case in their answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different approach: when I'm doing replacements, I prefer to think in terms of dictionaries.  So I'd do something like

```
>>> orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
>>> rep = {'c': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
>>> [i for c in orig for i in rep.get(c, [c])]
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd']
```

where the last line is the standard flattening idiom.

One advantage (disadvantage?) of this approach is that it'll handle multiple occurrences of `'c'`.

[update:]

Or, if you prefer:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(rep.get(c, [c]) for c in orig))
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd']
```

On the revised test case:

```
>>> orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c' ]
>>> rep = {'c': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(rep.get(c, [c]) for c in orig))
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Advantage! I should have made that clear in my question that I needed all instances replaced, not just the first.

Comment: @DSM -- That's the standard flattening idiom?  Somewhere along the way I missed that one -- Maybe it's because I still have a hard time parsing it :).  `itertools.chain` for me ...

Comment: @mgilson: well, it's the standard *listcomp* flattening idiom. :^)

Comment: Now that you've added `chain`, I'll upvote that :).  Although, it's worth pointing out that this answer imposes hashability on the list elements (at least for the ones you want to replace).  Most of the time, that's not a big deal, but occasionally it might be.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
>>> repl = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
>>> desired = list(orig)  #can skip this and just use `orig` if you don't mind modifying it (and it is a list already)
>>> desired[2:3] = repl
>>> desired
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd']
```

And of course, if you don't know that `'c'` is at index 2, you can use `orig.index('c')` to find out that information.

Comment: Deleted my answer as its almost same as yours :-)

Comment: You should do `desired = list(orig)` to make it more readable for beginners and to make valid the claim of working on any type of repl and orig

Comment: @JBernardo -- Fair enough :)  Good suggestion.  Edited.  Although, beginners should learn that `x[:]` is a shorthand way to copy a list -- (*statement without proof to follow*) It might be the fastest way to copy a list ...

Comment: Keep calling orig.index('c') until it finally throws ValueError? That's expensive and the code is rather awkward looking too.

Comment: @tdelaney -- when I posted, there was only 1 'c' in `orig` and no indication that OP wanted to replace multiple occurances.

Comment: @mgilson - sorry about that. I must have read the question after the update.

Answer (score 2):

No need for anything fancy:

```
desired = orig[:2] + repl + orig[3:]
```

To find `2` you can search for `orig.index('c')`.

```
x = orig.index('c')
desired = orig[:x] + repl + orig[x+1:]
```

if repl is not a list, just use `list(repl)`

Comment: fair enough (+1) ... Although this only works if the type of `repl` is the same as the type of `orig`.  My answer will even work if `repl` is a generator :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you enumerate backwards, you can extend the list as you go because the items you move have already gone through the enumeration.

```
>>> orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c' ]
>>> repl = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
>>> desired = [ 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
>>> for i in xrange(len(orig)-1, -1, -1):
...     if orig[i] == 'c':
...             orig[i:i+1] = repl
... 
>>> orig
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
>>> import operator
>>> orig = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c' ]
>>> repl = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
>>> output = [repl if x == 'c' else [x] for x in orig]
>>> reduce(operator.add, output)
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z']
>>>
```