# Replace elements in list - with a nested list containing said elements (python3)

Tags: python, list, replace, nested, nested-lists

I am trying to replace elements in a list with a list containig said elements, for example:

```
list = ['cow','orange','apple','mango']
to_replace = 'orange', 'apple'
replace_with = ['banana','cream']
```

Desired output:

```
['cow', ['banana', 'cream'], 'mango']
```

I've read the answers in this question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440360/replacing-an-item-in-list-with-items-of-another-list-without-using-dictionaries) and tried the function mentioned there:

```
def replace_item(list, to_replace, replace_with):
    for n,i in enumerate(list):
      if i== to_replace:
         list[n]=replace_with
    return list
```

but it does nothing. I also tried a basic equality functions:

```
list[1:3] = ['banana','cream']
```

However neither work. Is there a function to accomplish this? In my actual problem which is a loop, `list[1:3]` is an iterator, i.e. `list[i:i+2]`. I am not sure if this makes a difference. The items to be replaced will always be sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List[1:3] = [["banana", "cream"]]
```

The reason this isnt working is because when you are writing:
`List[1:3] = ["banana", "cream"]` 
you are replacing a list with a list. In other words you are changing `["orange", "apple"]` to `["banana", "cream"]`.

When doing this:
`List[1:3] = [["banana", "cream"]]`
you replace a list with a list in a list, replacing `["orange", "apple"]` with `[["banana","cream"]]`, thereby replacing `"orange", "apple"` with `["banana", "cream"]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def replace_item(lst, to_replace, replace_with):
    for n,i in enumerate(lst):
      if i in to_replace and lst[n+1] in to_replace:
         lst[n]=replace_with
         lst[n+1] = ""
    return [item for item in lst if item]

lst = ['cow','orange','apple','mango']
to_replace = 'orange', 'apple'
replace_with = ['banana','cream']

print (replace_item(lst, to_replace, replace_with))
```

Output:

```
['cow', ['banana', 'cream'], 'mango']
```

First, don't call your var the same name as object type. That is a bad idea that can lead to code confusion/bugs etc.

In your function, the problem was essentially that the `==` operator between a string (`i`) and a list (`lst`) will never say `True` regardless the rest. Plus, the content in string in the list is not the same as in your string. So you use `in` instead of `==`.

After this, if you don't want to have a duplicate and wish to replace adjacent `'orange', 'apple'` by a single `['banana','cream']`, you need to check `lst[n+1]` when iterating.

Then you replace `lst[n]`, set `lst[n+1]` to nothing and return a list purged from nothing elements using list comprehension.

Comment: thanks very much, for some reason in my loop this gives me "index out of range" error, not sure where the error is from but the solution above worked

Comment: Good! Think about accepting the answer if that helped ;)