# Create 2D array with the same size as another array and initialize with zero in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array in python, like the following:

```
2d_array_1 =[[0,1],[1,0]]
```

And want to create a second array of the same size, with all values initialized to zero.

How can I do that in python, if the size of the initial array can vary?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python for a 2d list you can use a nested list comprehension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding and replacing elements in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the size of a list by `len(list)` and you can initialise a list of length `n` with a given value `val` like this: `list = [val] * n`. Putting these two together you get:

```
first_array = [[0,1],[1,0]]
second_array = [ [0] * len(first_array[0]) ] * len( first_array )
```

assuming of course that `first_array` is of the form you're expecting.

Comment: you are simply duplicating the array len(first_array) times. This would lead to side effects. Sangwon has a better answer below that prevents that.

Answer (score 5):

I think above answer should be fixed.

```
first_array = [[0,1],[1,0]]
second_array = [ [0] * len(first_array[0]) ] * len( first_array )
second_array[0][0] = 1
print(second_array) # [[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

To prevent this, you can use below code

```
second_array = [ [0 for _ in range(len(first_array[0]))] for _ in range(len( first_array )) ]
second_array[0][0] = 1
print(second_array) # [[1, 0], [0, 0]]
```