# Split string but replace with another string and get list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I am trying to split a string but it should be replaced to another string and return as a list. Its hard to explain so here is an example:

I have string in variable `a`:

```
a = "Hello World!"
```

I want a list such that:

```
a.split("Hello").replace("Hey") == ["Hey"," World!"]
```

It means I want to split a string and write another string to that splited element in the list. SO if `a` is

```
a = "Hello World! Hello Everybody"
```

and I use something like `a.split("Hello").replace("Hey")` , then the output should be:

```
a = ["Hey"," World! ","Hey"," Everybody"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: a = a.replace('Hello','Hey').split('Hey') would work.

Comment: This link here to what you do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python

Comment: @EdwardKotarski Its not working with `HelloWorld!`. I don't have spaces in my original data. These are just examples.

Comment: @WongSiwei I don't want loops etc to make my program complex.

Comment: You should be more specific where you want to separate the string then. Do you want to separate by space or by the first uppercase character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = "HelloWorldHelloYou!" 
y = x.replace("Hello", "\nHey\n").lstrip("\n").split("\n") 
print(y) # ['Hey', 'World', 'Hey', 'You!']
```

This is a rather brute-force approach, you can replace `\n` with any character you're not expecting to find in your string (or even something like `XXXXX`). The `lstrip` is to remove `\n` if your string starts with `Hello`.

Alternatively, there's regex :)

Comment: why would someone downvote this answer? It seems to be the best so far.  well a bit of modification. try doing `x.replace("Hello", "\nHey\n").strip().split()` instead. This will split in spaces and line breaks too. Also it will do both stripping on both sides

Answer (score 1):

From your examples it sounds a lot like you want to replace all occurrences of `Hello` with `Hey` and then split on spaces.

What you are currently doing can't work, because `replace` needs two arguments and it's a method of strings, not lists. When you split your string, you get a list.

```
>>> a = "Hello World!"
>>> a = a.replace("Hello", "Hey")
>>> a
'Hey World!'
>>> a.split(" ")
['Hey', 'World!']
```

Answer (score 0):

this functions can do it

```
def replace_split(s, old, new):
    return sum([[blk, new for blk] in s.split(old)], [])[:-1]
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is extremely overcomplicated and doesn't answer the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

It wasnt clear if you wanted to split by space or by uppercase.

```
import re    

#Replace all 'Hello' with 'Hey'

a = 'HelloWorldHelloEverybody'
a = a.replace('Hello', 'Hey')

#This will separate the string by uppercase character

re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', a) #['Hey', 'World' ,'Hey' ,'Everybody']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with iteration:

```
a=a.split(' ')
for word in a:
    if word=='Hello':
      a[a.index(word)]='Hey'
```