# Python - Change item value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data I have zipped together using itertools.zip_longest

```
import itertools
names = 'Tim Bob Julian Carmen Sofia Mike Kim Andre'.split()
locations = 'DE ES AUS NL BR US'.split()
confirmed = [False, True, True, False, True]
zipped_up = list(itertools.zip_longest(names, locations, confirmed))
```

if I print zipped_up the way it is now I get the following:

```
[('Tim', 'DE', False), ('Bob', 'ES', True), 
('Julian','AUS', True), ('Carmen', 'NL', False), 
('Sofia', 'BR',True), ('Mike', 'US', None), 
('Kim',None, None),('Andre', None, None)]
```

This is fine, the missing values are given "None" as a default.  **Now I want to change the "None" values to '-'**.

It seems like I should be able to do so in the following nested loops. If I include a print statement in the code below, it appears everything works the way I wanted:

```
for items in zipped_up:
    for thing in items:
        if thing == None:
            thing = '-'
        print(thing)
```

But if I print zipped_up again (outside the loops), the 'None' values have not changed. Why Not? Is it something to do with the data type of the list items, which are tuples?

I have referenced some other stackoverflow threads including this one but have been unable to use it:
[finding and replacing elements in a list (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python)

Comment: "Why Not? Is it something to do with the data type of the list items, which are tuples?" No, not at all. `thing = '-'` simply assigns the value `'-'` to the local variable `thing`, and you shouldn't expect it to affect the list you are iterating over. There's definitely a duplicate somewhere, but I suggest your read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Can you just post the original before you zipped and your goal and maybe there is a better way

Comment: The best way to do this is to use `fillvalue`. But you can do the conversion by rebuilding the output, eg `[[thing or '-' for thing in items] for items in zipped_up]`, or `[tuple(thing or '-' for thing in items) for items in zipped_up]` if you need the inner sequences to be tuples.

Comment: @PM2Ring aren't we only using `zip_longest` over `zip` to utilize `fillvalue` to begin with?

Comment: @vash_the_stampede names, locations, and confirmed are the original data

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Kind of. It's main purpose is so the zipped-up list doesn't finish when the shortest source iterable is finished, but to do that we need some kind of fill value.

Comment: @PM2Ring that's what I'm saying, the whole purpose of `zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)` is for when we have uneven and need to use a fill, if not we would have used zip, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are trying to change elements in *tuples*, but tuples are *immutable* objects.
The only way to "change" them is to create *new* ones on the basis of *existing ones*.

Second, this part of your code

```
for thing in items:
    if thing == None:
        thing = '-'
```

replaces only the content of the *variable* `thing`, so even if you would have *mutable* objects in your `zipped_up` list - such as (nested) lists - your code *would not change them anyway*.

So, if your for whatever reason don't want to accept the [solution of sacul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415068/7023590) and instead edit your loop in loop approach, you may append *newly created tuples* to the new, empty list.

As in this (not very nice) code:

```
result = []
for a, b, c in zipped_up:
    a = '-' if a is None else a
    b = '-' if b is None else b
    c = '-' if c is None else c
    result.append((a, b, c))

print(result)
```

Output:

> [('Tim', 'DE', False), ('Bob', 'ES', True), ('Julian', 'AUS', True), ('Carmen', 'NL', False), ('Sofia', 'BR', True), ('Mike', 'US', '-'), ('Kim', '-', '-'), ('Andre', '-', '-')]

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `fillvalue` argument:

```
zipped_up = list(itertools.zip_longest(names, locations, confirmed, fillvalue='-'))

>>> zipped_up
[('Tim', 'DE', False), ('Bob', 'ES', True), ('Julian', 'AUS', True), ('Carmen', 'NL', False), ('Sofia', 'BR', True), ('Mike', 'US', '-'), ('Kim', '-', '-'), ('Andre', '-', '-')]
```

Comment: The important aspect of this question is probably explaining *why the OP's attempt didn't work*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but can we  say, why else would he use `zip_longest` over `zip` if not to use `fillvalue`?

Comment: Sure, and I would definitely point that out, but you are simply leaving them with a fundamental misunderstanding of the semantics of the language, and simply giving them an alternative solution.