# How to fix AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' when I try to replace some text in a csv read

Tags: python, csv, replace

I try to replace a text in csv read with some data dictionary, but I got an Error.

```py
import csv

dataset = open('../sentimenprabowo.csv', 'r')
sentiment = csv.reader(dataset, delimiter=',')

newDok = open('../sentimenprabowopreproses.csv', 'w')
save = csv.writer(newDok)

data= open("convertcsv.json", "r")
APPOSTOPHES=data.read()

new_sentence = []
for row in sentiment:     
    print(row)
    for candidate_replacement in APPOSTOPHES:                
        if candidate_replacement in row:            
            #print(candidate_replacement)
            row = row.replace(candidate_replacement, APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement])
    new_sentence.append(row)
rfrm = "".join(new_sentence)
print(rfrm)
```

I  hope this can be replace all the text in my csv who same text with data dictionary (correction spelling).

but the result is error:

```
  File "readdata.py", line 45, in <module>
    row = row.replace(candidate_replacement, APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

help me please...

this is my convertcsv.json file:

```
{"@":"di","ababil":"abg labil","abis":"habis","acc":"accord","ad":"ada","adlah":"adalah"}
```

Comment: `replace` can only apply to `str`, seems `row` is `list` here.

Comment: so, how to fix it?

Comment: To replace list items check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python

Comment: I think you should figure out the composition of your data, I can not debug the context, maybe `for s in row`?

Answer (score 3):

As the error says your row is a list and doesn't have replace method. You can convert it to string replace as you wish then again cast to array:

```
row = str(row).replace(candidate_replacement, APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement]).split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with list comparison

use this

```
for r in range(len(row)):
    if row[r] == candidate_replacement:
        row[r] = APPOSTOPHES[candidate_replacement]
```