# Support needed on converting string to regular expression

Tags: python

I have a string like `'((30 >=50) and (20 <= 100)) or (52 > 35)'`.

I want to convert this to a regular expression and evaluate.

For example, `value = ((30 >=50) and (20 <= 100)) or (52 > 35)`

Should return true or false based on evaluating this expression

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand the input is `'((30 >=50) and (20 <= 100)) or (52 > 35)'` what should be the output?

Comment: @j.doe `true` or `false` as OP stated, depending on how the expression is evaluated

Comment: did you mean **(false & true) or (true)** which in turn results  **true**?

Comment: Why do you think that you could do this with a regular expression? I would say it's more a task for a parser generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval() to get the result of your string.

In your case, it will be `value = eval('((30 >=50) and (20 <= 100)) or (52 > 35)')`

Comment: I believe that what OP is talking about is not regex, but the literal meaning of a regular expression. OP likely does not know what regex is.

Comment: @ArulanandNagarajan Please accept my answer as the correct answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Also one more question. How can i replace a list of strings with another. For example i have 2 lists. list1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] and list2 = ['80.0', '20.0', '25.0']. I want to replace the list1 strings with respective list2 strings in the expression OP = ((aa >= 50) and (bb<=100)) or (cc == 25). Is there a single python command to replace a list of strings with another?

Comment: @ArulanandNagarajan [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list-python) might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine if a string with arbitrary number of parentheses is actually syntactically correct (i.e. every parenthesis is closed) using regular expressions because it's fundamentally more complex (you need a stack-based solution to solve a context-free grammar class problem) than what a regular expression can handle (a simple DFA).

So you need to reconsider how you're approaching this problem.

That said, here's a small program that checks if the expression has balanced number of parentheses and then evaluates the result.

```py
def is_correct_expression(expr: str) -> bool:
    pars = []
    try:
        for c in expr:
            if c == '(':
                pars.append(c)
            if c == ')':
                pars.pop()
        return True
    except IndexError:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = '((30 >=50) and (20 <= 100)) or (52 > 35)'

    if is_correct_expression(expr):
        result = eval(expr)
        print(result)
    else:
        print('invalid expression')
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: thank you. using eval function solves my problem. and yes using the is_correct_expression function, i could validate my expression before evaluating it.

Comment: Also one more question. How can i replace a list of strings with another. For example i have 2 lists. list1 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] and list2 = ['80.0', '20.0', '25.0']. I want to replace the list1 strings with respective list2 strings in the expression OP = ((aa >= 50) and (bb<=100)) or (cc == 25). Is there a single python command to replace a list of strings with another?