# How to replace a value in the list, ex:- [5,4,6,1,2] replace 4 with 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

Replacing the value in the list

List

```
a=[5,6,7,5,8,7]
```

replace 7 with 3

required output

```
[5,6,3,5,8,7]
```

Condition?

With out slice?

Comment: In this link if list have 2 or more value of same number all numbers are replaced but i  want to change only specific location value?

Comment: Just use the index.... Thats primarily what `[ ]` is for. `my_list[2] = 3`. If you have trouble with this you should really just follow a tutorial on python. (Technically this is a standard feature for almost all core languages)

Comment: @Ashokkumarreddy What you indicate in your comment does not match the example you provide in your question

Comment: @Ashokkumarreddy From your edition I understand that if there are several items with the same value (in your example "7") you only want to change the first value. Am I correct? If so, then use: `for n, i in enumerate(a):` `if i == 7:` `a[n] = 3` `break`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[3 if x==7 else x for x in a]
```

Comment: i want to replace only specified location value that i want to replace with given value

Comment: If you want to change a location (e.g. the first element), you can use `a[0] = 3`