# Line comprehension is not functioning correctly in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

**I want to know why the code listed below is not functioning correctly.It should print 'Hi' but it is not printing it.Please look into this matter.Thanks in advance.**

```
a=['{','}']
a=[(s.replace('{','H'),s.replace('}','i'))for s in a]
print(a)
```

Comment: A list of tuples is not a string

Comment: You are replacing each element of the list with a tuple, not just updating an element

Comment: What is meant by that?Can you please explain it.

Comment: The code works correctly. If your real question is how to replace items in a list, that was already covered before multiple times, e.g. here: [finding and replacing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582138/7851470).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working properly.
On the first element of the list, it encounters `'{'` which is computed to `'H'` by `s.replace('{','H')` although '{' remains the same by applying `s.replace('}','i')` because the closing bracket (`'}'`) is not encountered. Therefore, the result is `('H','{')`.

The same logic on the second element of the list.

Comment: So why the '{' is printed.Using replace should not let it print

Comment: if the string to be replaced is not found, the initial string is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
a=['{','}']
a=[(s.replace('{','H').replace('}','i'))for s in a]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['H', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two operations, comma-separated in brackets, which produces two values, called a tuple (one result for each replace operation). Here's how to do what you want:

```
[s.replace('}','i').replace('{','H') for s in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to being with. 
1. You are trying to return a tuple and not a string, so 'Hi' is not possible. You would get '[('H', '{'), ('}', 'i')]'. 
2. For string try below code. You should try replace on the list that is already replaced and then extract string out of it.

`a=['{','}']
a=[s.replace('{', "H") for s in a]
a=[s.replace('}',"i") for s in a]
print("".join(a))`

below is the single line code with same result.

`a=['{','}']
print("".join([s.replace('{', "H").replace("}", "i") for s in a]))`