# Compare two lists of lists and fill in blank values

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm reading data from an API and have a list of lists like this:

```
listData = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), -6.78125], 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), -6.125], 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), -5.90625]]
```

I need to create a complete list filling in the missing values. I've created a destination, like this:

```
listDest = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), None], 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 6, 0), None], 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), None],
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), None]]
```

The end result should look like this:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), -6.78125],
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 6, 0), None],
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), -6.125], 
[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), -5.90625]]
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
for blankTime, blankValue in listDest:
    for dataTime, dataValue in listData:
        if blankTime == dataTime:
            blankIndex = listDest.index(blankTime)
            dataIndex = listData.index(dataTime)
            listDest[blankIndex] = tempRm7[dataIndex]
```

This returns the following error, which is confusing since I know that value is in both lists.

```
ValueError: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0) is not in list
```

I attempted to adapt the methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582138/5560474) but that's for a 1D list and I couldn't figure out how to make it work for my 2D list.

Comment: Are both `listData` and `listDest` sorted by the datetime?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, both are sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both lists are sorted, you can merge them and then group them (using [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)/[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)):

```
import datetime
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby


listData = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), -6.78125],
            [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), -6.125],
            [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), -5.90625]]

listDest = [[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), None],
            [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 6, 0), None],
            [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), None],
            [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), None]]

out = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(merge(listData, listDest, key=lambda k: k[0]), lambda k: k[0])]

# pretty print to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 5, 0), -6.78125],
 [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 6, 0), None],
 [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 7, 0), -6.125],
 [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 8, 0), -5.90625]]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Is this what's called "list comprehension"? I need to spend some time understanding exactly how that works. The syntax is inscrutable to me.