# Random substitution

Tags: python, dictionary, key, txt

I have a txt file and a dictionary, where keys are adjectives, values are their synonyms. I need  to replace the common adjectives from the dictionary which I meet in a given txt file with their synonyms - randomly! and save both versions - with changed and unchanged adjectives - line by line - in a new file(task3_edited_text). My code:

```
#get an English text as a additional input
filename_eng = sys.argv[2]
infile_eng = open(filename_eng, "r")
task3_edited_text = open("task3_edited_text.txt", "w")

#necessary for random choice
import random 

#look for adjectives in English text
#line by line
for line in infile_eng:
    task3_edited_text.write(line)
    line_list = line.split()
    #for each word in line
    for word in line_list:
        #if we find common adjectives, change them into synonym, randomly
        if word in dict.keys(dictionary):
            word.replace(word, str(random.choice(list(dictionary.values()))))
        else:
            pass
    task3_edited_text.write(line)
```

Problem is in the output adjectives are not substituted by their values.

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The `replace` method returns a new string. It doesn't modify the string object on which it is called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding and replacing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: You need to make a new list where each item is either the original word or a substitution from the dictionary. You don't need `.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
line_list = line.split()
...
task3_edited_text.write(line)
```

The issue is that you try to modify `line_list`, which you created from `line`. However, `line_list` is simply a list made from copying values generated from `line` ; modifying it doesn't change `line` in the slightest. So writing `line` to the file writes the unmodified line to the file, and doesn't take your changes into account.

You probably want to generate a `line_to_write` from `line_list`, and writing it to the file instead, like so:

```
line_to_write = " ".join(line_list)
task3_edited_text.write(line_to_write)
```

Also, `line_list` isn't even modified in your code as `word` is a copy of an element in `line_list` and not a reference to the original. Moreover, `replace` returns a copy of a string and doesn't modify the string you call it on. You probably want to modify `line_list` via the index of the elements like so:

```
for idx, word in enumerate(line_list):
    #if we find common adjectives, change them into synonym, randomly
    if word in dict.keys(dictionary):
        line_list[idx] = word.replace(word, str(random.choice(list(dictionary.values()))))
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: `line_list` isn't modified either in the original code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 You're absolutely correct. I'm editing my answer