# python list replace only if it is a exact match using list comprehension

Tags: python, replace, list-comprehension

I have the following list :-

`list= ['order','orderNumber']`

I want enclose `order` in double_quotes "order" not orderNumber
I tried the below in list comprehension

```
if 'order' in list:
     list = [item.replace('order', '"' + 'order' + '"') for item in list]
```

But the output is :- order from orderNumber is also getting enclosed with double quotes which is not needed

> ['"order"', '"order"Number']

Exepected Output is :-

> ['"order"', 'orderNumber']

Comment: Can you just change `list[0]`?

Comment: why you need to double quotes?

Comment: It could be anywhere in the list

Comment: You are checking if `order` in `list` then modifying all the items if `True`.  You need to check in the comprehension as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `==` operator and not `in` as:

```
lst = ['order','orderNumber']
lst = [f'"{elt}"' if elt == 'order' else elt for elt in lst]
print(lst)
```

Also, don't use `list` for object names.

---

Update: Use concatenation operator `+` for Python version less that 3.6 that don't support `fstrings`.

```
lst = ['order','orderNumber']
lst = ['"{}"'.format(elt) if elt == 'order' else elt for elt in lst]
print(lst)
```

Comment: thanks..works...f stands for replacement..?

Comment: f short for fstrings is used for formatting strings

Comment: works with python3...but for python 2.7 doesnot support F prefix ...is there an alternative apart from using regex

Comment: added the code with contenation operator `+` without fstrings.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia: I'd suggest either just using `'"order"'` (since it's literally that one string we're handling, we don't need to work in terms of the loop variable), or if you hate repeating yourself (wouldn't blame you), `'"{}"'.format(elt)`, for a solution that works back to 2.6 (creates output directly, similar to the f-string, rather than producing a temporary intermediate string; `str.format` is the predecessor to f-strings, that are a more powerful version of `str.format` supported directly by language syntax). Pre-2.6, `'"%s"' % elt` (`'"%s"' % (elt,)` when `elt` might be a `tuple`).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment @ShadowRanger. I have updated the answer with using `format()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['order', 'orderNumber']
>>> [re.sub('^order$', '"order"', item) for item in lst]
>>> ['"order"', 'orderNumber']
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if the below works for you

```
lista = ['order','orderNumber']
listb = []
if 'order' in lista:
    for item in lista:
        if item == 'order':
            listb.append(item.replace('order', '"' + 'order' + '"'))
        else:
            listb.append(item)
lista = listb
```

Comment: 1) Code-only answers are generally frowned on, especially when they're making huge changes to the original code and the relevance of any given change is unclear. 2) This is wildly overcomplicating things (e.g. when you know, for a fact, the string is just `'order'`, you nevertheless rely on `str.replace` to make an updated version, when you could just do `listb.append('"order"')`.

Comment: 3) With a listcomp, making a new `list` is unavoidable, but when the intent is to update in place, as you (sort of) do when you reassign `lista` at the end, you don't need to build a new `list`; `for i, item in enumerate(lista): if item == 'order': lista[i] = '"order"'` would avoid the need to build a new `list`, and keep the work to near-zero for all the elements that are left unchanged. And on thinking of this, I checked for duplicates of this question, and lo and behold, [the accepted answer on the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582183/364696) does this. :-)