# How do you change a number in a list to another number

Tags: python

How do I change a number in a list *without* knowing the position the number is in? For example, if I had:

`numbers = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]`

Say I wanted to change the number 11 to 1 and I do not know that 11 is in position 0.

I do not want to do something like,

```
if 11 in numbers:
    number[11] = 1
```

because this would change number 10 to 1.
So, no matter where the 11 is in the list, it will replace it with a 1.

The code above is basically checking if there is an 11 in the list and if there is, it will replace it with 1.

Comment: `number[11]` is the 12th (due to 0-based indexing) element in the list, not whichever one (if any) happens to have the value `11`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. I am trying to find out how i would get the value 11 changed to 1. No matter what position it is in.

Comment: Then are you asking "how do I find the index of a value in a list?" and, if so, have you tried any research to figure that out?

Comment: Originally, the thought of finding the index of the value did not occur to me. I did do research, but I was searching with the wrong question. Though I am grateful someone gave the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `index` method of `list` objects.

```
numbers[numbers.index(11)] = 1
```

It will fail if `11` is not in `numbers`.
It will replace only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the indexes of the list:

```
numbers = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] == 11:
        numbers[i] = 1

print(numbers)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, you can do this a thousand different ways.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to do this, but [this answer to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59478892/3216427) seems to be the fastest solution, with [benchmarks in this other answer to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59826095/3216427).

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [x if x is not 11 else 1 for x in numbers]
```

Comment: This makes a brand new list. OP seems to be asking to change the initial list

Comment: @OneCricketeer, but this new list will replace previous, what's the problem?

Comment: like a homework? :)  @OneCricketeer

Comment: @Olvin Depending on space requirements, allocates unnecessary memory

Comment: @OneCricketeer, to not allocate additional memory you can use `numbers[:] = (x if x is not 11 else 1 for x in numbers)`

Comment: if you want to mutate the list, you have to find the element (`index` method), but I don't suggest mutation for small lists