# Turn every element of a 2D array from a dic into a string with ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that displays the board as a list of list (the way as it is) with '_' (hidden squares), '.'
(bombs), ' ' (empty squares), or '1', '2', etc.

```
game = {'dimensions': [2, 4],
            'board': [['.', 3, 1, 0],
                      ['.', '.', 1, 0]],
            'mask': [[False, True, False, False],
                     [False, False, False, False]],
            'state': 'ongoing'}
```

expected return

```
[['.', '3', '1', ' '],
['.', '.', '1', ' ']]
```

My attempt to change it in place:

```
def transform(game):
    for outer in game['board']:
            for inner in outer:
                if inner ==0: 
                    inner =' '
                else: 
                    inner = "\'"+str(inner)+"\'"
                    print("inner", inner)
                    print(type(inner))
        return game['board']
```

I got print of each inner to be string in the desired format, but the final return didn't get changed at all?? :

```
 ...
 inner '3'
 <class 'str'>
 inner '1'
 <class 'str'>
 inner ...
  

[['.', 3, 1, 0],['.', '.', 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding and replacing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582138/finding-and-replacing-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: you need change `outer[{the index of inner}]`, not change `inner`.

Comment: @anatolyg not really. i see my solution is the same as the most voted solution the question you referred. except i didn't write it in one-liner. But how come it didn't change the final results??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need change `outer[{the index of inner}]`, not change `inner`.The one-liner solution which use list comprehension is to **create** a new list, not to **change** the old list.

one-liner solution:

```
game = {'dimensions': [2, 4],
            'board': [['.', 3, 1, 0],
                      ['.', '.', 1, 0]],
            'mask': [[False, True, False, False],
                     [False, False, False, False]],
            'state': 'ongoing'}

def transform(game):
    return [[' ' if inner == 0 else "\'"+str(inner)+"\'" for inner in outer] for outer in game['board']]

print(transform(game))
```

result:

```
[["'.'", "'3'", "'1'", ' '], ["'.'", "'.'", "'1'", ' ']]
```

**EDIT**:If you dont want use one-liner and `list comprehension` to create new list, you can try this code.

code:

```
def transform_create(game_board):
    result = []
    for board in game_board:
        temp = []
        for item in board:
            if item == 0:
                temp.append(' ')
            else:
                temp.append("\'"+str(item)+"\'")
        result.append(temp)
    return result
print(transform_create(game["board"]))
```

result:

```
[["'.'", "'3'", "'1'", ' '], ["'.'", "'.'", "'1'", ' ']]
```

Comment: on a side note, if i want to create a new list, but not using one liner, is there a way to do it? (not the enumerate method)